# Xcode and dylib search path

Tags: xcode, macos, dyld, search-path

I have a framework with installation directory `@rpath` and app with runpath search path `@loader_path/../Frameworks` which uses this framework.

After building I have `My.app` and `My.framework` in `Build/Products/Debug` directory and I **don't** copy `My.framework` into `My.app` bundle.

If I run `My.app` from Xcode it runs and loads framework from `Build/Products/Debug` directory. If I run my app from Finder it can't load the framework as expected.

Does Xcode set runtime search path and how? DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Xcode sets both `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH` to point to your built product directory when it runs your application.

Comment: how? where can we view this?